# How to restructure positions of product media or remove all images using product api in Shopware

Tags: api, rest, shopware6, shopware6-api

So I have an product and want to change the position of its images and swap the cover image, while adding some more images to the medias assigned to the product.
The media should look somewhat like this:

```
{
  "media": [
    {
      "id": "a060944a2938442c8d461b3a0107ecf5",
      "mediaId": "722d194bfbb84dc489f9f5b74da53bb3",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "b060944a2938442c8d461b3a0107ecf6",
      "mediaId": "822d194bfbb84dc489f9f5b74da53bb4",
      "position": 2
    }
  ],
  "coverId": "a060944a2938442c8d461b3a0107ecf5"
}
```

and change to this:

```
{
  "media": [
    {
      "id": "a060944a2938442c8d461b3a0107ecf5",
      "mediaId": "722d194bfbb84dc489f9f5b74da53bb3",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "b060944a2938442c8d461b3a0107ecf6",
      "mediaId": "822d194bfbb84dc489f9f5b74da53bb4",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "c060944a2938442c8d461b3a0107ecf7",
      "mediaId": "922d194bfbb84dc489f9f5b74da53bb5",
      "position": 1
    }
  ],
  "coverId": "b060944a2938442c8d461b3a0107ecf6"
}
```

I couldn't find a way to restructure the media positions and change the cover image.
So I tried to remove the media from the product, but the cover image stills stays even though the medias aren't connected to the product any more.
Also an UPDATE on the coverId doesn't seem to do the job either.

I used this to remove the images:

```
DELETE https://your-page.com/api/product/5efd4f22dc134ba7bf77c85f92fed0a9/media/b060944a2938442c8d461b3a0107ecf6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cover` and `media` are two separate associations, so removing all `media` associations can still leave the `cover` association intact.

- `new ManyToOneAssociationField('cover', 'product_media_id', ProductMediaDefinition::class, 'id')`
- `new OneToManyAssociationField('media', ProductMediaDefinition::class, 'product_id')`

Notice how both refer to the definition `ProductMediaDefinition`. That means for `coverId` you have to provide the `id` of an existing `product_media` entity, not of a `media` entity.

If you have the id of a media entity, you can also create the `product_media` entity on the fly:

```json
{
  "id": "{productId}",
  "cover": {
    "mediaId": "{mediaId}"
  }
}
```

If you want to remove the cover image without setting a new one, you can set `coverId` to `null`.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot.  
That seems to work out.  
Didn't thought about nulling the field...